# WordPress query: merge meta key (number) values and sort

Tags: query, advanced-custom-fields, meta-query

There's a lot of [great documentation](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/03/30/query-improvements-in-wp-4-2-orderby-and-meta_query/) on multiple column sorting using `orderby` however I can't seem to find a good `WP_Query` solution to this problem.

Each post has two meta keys: `rating_au` and `rating_overall`.

I want to query posts by `rating_au` as a priority and then falling back to `rating_overall` if no value for `rating_au` exists.

**Example Table**

```
| post ID | rating_au | rating_overall |
|---------|-----------|----------------|
| 1       |           | 80             |
| 2       | 90        | 75             |
| 3       |           | 70             |
```

**Example Output**

- 2
- 1
- 3

I have got as far as the following query:

```
$args = [
  'posts_per_page' => 5,
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'meta_query' => [
    'relation' => 'OR',
    'rating_au_clause' => [
      'key' => 'rating_au',
      'compare' => 'EXISTS'
    ],
    'rating_overall_clause' => [
      'key' => 'rating_overall',
      'compare' => 'EXISTS'
    ]
  ],
  'orderby' => 'rating_au_clause rating_overall_clause',
  'order' => 'DESC'
];
```

I think I'm probably misunderstanding how this translates to MySQL but it does not produce the desired outcome (it simply lists descending order for `rating_overall`).

I'm wracking my brains on this and am looking to avoid `$wpdb` or running multiple queries and merging values.

It's likely there's an entirely different approach to this problem. Any suggestions are gratefully received!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the syntax you are after:

```
$args = [
  'posts_per_page' => 5,
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'meta_query' => [
    'relation' => 'OR',
    'rating_au_clause' => [
      'key' => 'rating_au',
      'compare' => 'EXISTS'
    ],
    'rating_overall_clause' => [
      'key' => 'rating_overall',
      'compare' => 'EXISTS'
    ]
  ],
  'orderby' => [ 
        'rating_au_clause' => 'ASC',
        'rating_overall_clause' => 'DESC',
    ],
];
```

It's a subtle difference, but uses your named meta queries in an orderby array.

Comment: I believe this is the same query just structured differently and using ASC for `rating_au_clause`. Unfortunately this doesn't achieve the desired result mentioned above.